# How can i insert only into one column without getting null to others

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to insert into a data-base column without overwriting values for other columns.. Heres my php code where I check every column if it has to be overwritten with "si" or no value at all.. The thing is only last column gets the value "si" and all of others a value of "null".. HOw can i insert only into one column without getting null or '' to the others!

```
if($canSend){

            $queryUser="CREATE TABLE `$email` ( lun8semanauno VARCHAR(30), 
                            lun10semanauno VARCHAR(30), lun16semanauno VARCHAR(30),lun18semanauno VARCHAR(30), lun20semanauno VARCHAR(30));";
            $queryu=mysql_query($queryUser,$db); 
 }

//Ahora sumo uno al cupo si es que esta todo bien de arriba:    
    if($canSend && $horarios == "Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal"){
            $nuevocupolun8=$info['cuposLun8']+1;
            $queryRestar="UPDATE  `cupos` SET  `cuposLun8`='$nuevocupolun8'   WHERE  `cupos`.`cuposLun8` =  '$cupolun8';";
            $restar=mysql_query($queryRestar,$db);

            $queryAdd="INSERT INTO `lahiguera_hor`.`$email` (`lun8semanauno`) VALUES ('si');";
            $querya=mysql_query($queryAdd,$db);
        }
    if($canSend && $horarios == "Lunes 10hs-Meditacion"){
            $nuevocupolun10=$info['cuposLun10']+1;
            $queryRestar="UPDATE  `cupos` SET  `cuposLun10`='$nuevocupolun10'   WHERE  `cupos`.`cuposLun10` =  '$cupolun10';";
            $restar=mysql_query($queryRestar,$db);

            $queryAdd="$queryAdd="INSERT INTO `lahiguera_hor`.`$email` (`lun10semanauno`) VALUES ('si');";
            $querya=mysql_query($queryAdd,$db);
        }
    if($canSend && $horarios == "Lunes 16hs-Futuras mamas"){
            $nuevocupolun16=$info['cuposLun16']+1;
            $queryRestar="UPDATE  `cupos` SET  `cuposLun16`='$nuevocupolun16'   WHERE  `cupos`.`cuposLun16` =  '$cupolun16';";
            $restar=mysql_query($queryRestar,$db);

            $queryAdd="INSERT INTO `lahiguera_hor`.`$email` (`lun16semanauno`) VALUES ('si');";
            $querya=mysql_query($queryAdd,$db);
        }       
    if($canSend && $horarios == "Lunes 18hs-Clase grupal"){
            $nuevocupolun18=$info['cuposLun18']+1;
            $queryRestar="UPDATE  `cupos` SET  `cuposLun18`='$nuevocupolun18'   WHERE  `cupos`.`cuposLun18` =  '$cupolun18';";
            $restar=mysql_query($queryRestar,$db);

            $queryAdd="INSERT INTO `lahiguera_hor`.`$email` (`lun18semanauno`) VALUES ('si');";
            $querya=mysql_query($queryAdd,$db);
        }           
    if($canSend && $horarios == "Lunes 20hs-clase grupal"){
            $nuevocupolun18=$info['cuposLun20']+1;
            $queryRestar="UPDATE  `cupos` SET  `cuposLun20`='$nuevocupolun20'   WHERE  `cupos`.`cuposLun20` =  '$cupolun20';";
            $restar=mysql_query($queryRestar,$db);

            $queryAdd="INSERT INTO `lahiguera_hor`.`$email` (`lun20semanauno`) VALUES ('si');";
            $querya=mysql_query($queryAdd,$db);
        }
```

Comment: what do you expect to have in the others, different than null ?!

Comment: if you are `INSERT`ing, then the other column's won't HAVE a value.  are you sure you aren't supposed to be looking at `UPDATE`?

Comment: `$queryAdd="$queryAdd="INSERT INTO `lahiguera_hor`.`$email` (`lun10semanauno`) VALUES ('si');";` this is totally wrong... your quotes are in collision...

Comment: UPDATE will change the values in existing rows that match the criteria, where INSERT will create a new row with specified values (and default values for all other fields, NULL unless otherwise specified when you create the table/field).

If you want one row with values set as you go along, then use one INSERT and a series of UPDATEs. If you want several rows, then you need to specify values for all fields in the INSERT statement (otherwise the default will be used).

You can auto-populate them with data from other rows using INSERT.... SELECT... notation rather than INSERT... VALUES(...).

Comment: @ChrisFlynn That's basically an answer!

Comment: THanks for the reply! I changed to UPDATE claus, anyway its not working! -->

$queryAdd="UPDATE  `$email` SET  `lun8semanauno`='si'   WHERE  `$email`.`lun8semanauno` =  'no';";
   $querya=mysql_query($queryAdd,$db);
I included 'no' as default when creating the table

Comment: What do you mean "its not working"? Can you describe how you know it's not working? Does it give an error? Or just not update any rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting new row into database and you dont specify values for each column, default value will be set or NULL if allowed for that column otherwise databse will return an error and will not write the row into table.

for INT columns set default value 0, for VARCHAR columns you can specify '' empty string as default. Everything depends on your design of database, on how you would like to use it. If you dont want anything in column, you can allow it to be NULL, and preset default value NULL. Using NULL as an empty value is a good habit.